# Should i use present participle or infinitive verb

Tags: grammar

I am trying to construct an sentence but i get a little problem with it. The sentence i want t o make is " when the guestes arrived in the centre, they fand five greeters standing by the gate welcome[welcoming] them'.  I dont know i should use 'welcome' or 'welcoming' here, and why?

Comment: fand? Is supposed to be 'and' or 'found'?

Answer (score 2):

It's neither infinitive (welcome) nor present participle (welcoming). Instead, you should use to-infinitive (to welcome).

Comment: "welcoming them" indicates what the greeters are doing is doing "to welcome them" indicates the greeters' purpose. Without knowing the meaning intended, it is wrong to rule out either.